# How to format city and state from dashes to spaces with a comma between city and state code. (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I have a string `Atlantic-City-NJ` How do I use JavaScript regular expressions (or any other way) to format the string to `Atlantic City, NJ`?

I'm having issues because there can be an varying amount of spaces: `Atlanta, GA` vs `Atlantic City, NJ` vs `Lake Havasu City, AZ`

Comment: are the states going to be represented by their 2 character codes?

Comment: are all the initial strings spaces replaced with dashes ?

Comment: @TaraLerias see my revised answer, sorry had misread question

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly make use of [U.S. state codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_abbreviations), but if validation is not important, you can get everything done like this:

```js
var str = "Atlantic-City-NJ";
alert(str.replace(/(.+)\-([A-Z]{2})$/, "$1, $2").replace("\-", " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression will give you two parts:

```
([\w-]+)([A-Z]{2})
```

"Atlantic-City-" and "NJ".

You can take those two parts, do a string replace on the first to turn hyphens into spaces, then form a string out of the result, a comma, plus the second part.

Let me know if you would like more detail.

Comment: I asked OP if the state is going to be represented as codes. If not your regex wont work

Comment: Given the test data, I suspect the data does have state abbreviations. Otherwise, more information would be needed about format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var test = "Atlantic-City-NJ";
test = test.split("-");
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  if (i == test.length - 1)
    result += ",";
  result += " " + test[i];
}
//result = "Atlantic City, NJ"
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following expression will match the last hyphen (-) and the country code

`/([\w-]+)(-(([^-])+)$)/`

With this you could do

`string.replace(/([\w-]+)(-(([^-])+)$)/, '$1, $3').replace(/-/g, ' ')`

This will replace the last hyphen and country code with a comma and the country code as well as replacing the rest of the hyphens with spaces.

Regex description:

```
1st Capturing group ([\w-]+)
  [\w-]+ match a single character present in the list below
  Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]

  - the literal character -

    2nd Capturing group (-(([^-])+)$)
      - matches the character - literally

      3rd Capturing group (([^-])+)

      4th Capturing group ([^-])+
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        [^-] match a single character not present in the list below
          - the literal character -

            $ assert position at end of the string
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var cs = ["Lake-Havasu-City-AZ", "Altanta-GA", "Atlantic-City-NJ", "Atlantic-City"];
for ( var i in cs )
   console.log(cs[i].replace( new RegExp('-([A-Z]+)$'), ', $1').replace('-',' ','g'))
// prints...
Lake Havasu City, AZ
Altanta, GA
Atlantic City, NJ
Atlantic City
```

You can replace `[A-Z]+` with `[A-Z]{2}` if you wanted to be more concise for state code.